# How to change Ecto relationships

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm a new in Elixir and looking for proper way of how to chanage relationship in Ecto model.

Assume I have model with relationship:

```
 schema "topic" do
      has_many :topic_meta, PhoenixApp.TopicMeta
```

And query with preload:

```
 topic = from t in query,
        left_join: meta in assoc(t, :topic_meta),
        preload: [topic_meta: meta] 
        |> Repo.one
```

Get map `%PhoenixApp.Topic{...}` with list field `topic_meta`

I want change value in one of `topic_meta` fields:

```
 changed_meta = %{List.first(topic.topic_meta) | last_read: "newValue"}
```

**Question:**

How to insert changed `topic_meta` relation filed to `topic` from my query? Make a new query for updating fields looks like unnecessary.

**Update in details:**

```
first_meta = List.first(topic.topic_meta) // this is first meta

result =  Repo.update!(PhoenixApp.Topic.changeset(first_meta, %{last_read: "newValue"}))

case result do
  {:ok, topic_meta}        ->  
 // topic_meta successfully updated, but topic does not contain this model
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your `changed_meta` in shape you want to update, you should use [`Repo.update/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update/2):

```
Repo.update(changed_meta)
```

Hope that helps!

**Update**

If you want to see element updated in your `topic` without reloading it, you could replace current list of `topic_meta` manually.

Given you have prepared `change_meta`, you could do something like:

```
index = Enum.find_index(topic.topic_meta &(&1.id == changed_meta.id))
list  = List.replace_at(topic.topic_meta, index, changed_meta)
topic = %{topic | topic_meta: list}
```

With this, the `topic` from the last line will have updated list of `topic_meta`, containing the one of `changed_meta`.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I detailed the question in the section 'Update in details'. The question was how to merge `Repo.update` result with original data.

Comment: Oh! I see what you're asking about. I'm afraid there is no "easy" way of doing so, due to immutability. `topic` is not anything like objects (eg. in Ruby/Java), thus such a change is not reflected immediately. The easiest way of reflect it would be just to reload the data from database. Here, the division for actions in Phoenix makes sense - you update the values in `update` action, and redirect user to sort of `show` action, where the updated data is fetched clean from DB.

Comment: Hey @user1156168 -  please, take a look at updated answer. Code is quite verbose (comparing to what you would have if you did similar thing in OO language), but it should do what you expect. Hope that clarifies the problem a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Use `build_assoc` https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3

```
changed_meta = Ecto.build_assoc(topic, :topic_meta, last_read: "newValue")
Repo.insert!(comment)
```

Comment: Case clear for new `topic_meta`, but waht to do when associasions already preload.